# Import modules not working in javascript file

Tags: javascript, npm

I installed a few apis via npm. I am trying to import it but get an error that it won't work. If I remove the code everything will work besides,

```
const visualizer = butterchurn.createVisualizer(audioContext, canvas, {
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});
```

then, it works.

```
import butterchurn from "butterchurn";
import butterchurnPresets from "butterchurn-presets";

alert("sup");
//callback
//initalize audio context and get canvas
// initialize audioContext and get canvas

//window.navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true, video:false}, userMediaCallback);

//intialize audioContext and get canvas
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")


let userMediaCallback = stream => {

    let audioContext = new AudioContext()
    let mic = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    const visualizer = butterchurn.createVisualizer(audioContext, canvas, {
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });

    // get audioNode from audio source or microphone

    visualizer.connectAudio(mic);
    
    // load a preset

    const presets = butterchurnPresets.getPresets();
    const preset = presets['Flexi, martin + geiss - dedicated to the sherwin maxawow'];

    visualizer.loadPreset(preset, 0.0); // 2nd argument is the number of seconds to blend presets

    // resize visualizer

    visualizer.setRendererSize(1600, 1200);

    // render a frame
    
    visualizer.render();
    

}

window.navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, userMediaCallback, console.log);
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at index.js:2:1)

doesn't make sense to me because I am pulling from the npm json module?

Comment: Is your script inside a script block with `type="module"`? - **The `import` statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a `type="module"`.** - [MDN import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: No its in an external javascript file that is called in the head of the file

Comment: The three periods below the from butterchurn says "Could not find a declaration file for module 'butterchurn-presets'. 'C:/audioVisualizzer/root/node_modules/butterchurn-presets/lib/butterchurnPresets.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Im confused on what this means if everything is coming up right in the json file

Comment: When i leave the import out it says 

butterchurn.createVisualizer is not a function, 

however, it should be working so I dont know why its being called like that

Comment: WEb audio api works without import so I dont even know if I need the import or not

Comment: Load the script with `<script src="/path/to/yourScript.js" type="module">` and the `import`-statement will work. The error you mentioned comes from the missing `type="module"`. You might take a look at [MDN: Guide Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html).

Comment: So thatll fix that one error, but then it'll state "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "butterchurn". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." and the rest of the code won't work. I've been running this circle for days. Can i have other code in a module?

Comment: The json looks like this

"dependencies": {
    "butterchurn": "^2.6.7",
    "butterchurn-presets": "^2.4.7",
    "from": "^0.1.7",
    "gl": "^5.0.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "sever": "^0.0.2",
    "web-audio-api": "^0.2.2"

So i should be able to just pull by the string name?

Comment: Do I even need to import if I installed these with npm and they are in the package.json file?

Comment: Fixed. I didn't need to import it, i needed to add a .default to the visualizer. Sorry this api is hard to find documentation on. Thank you.